# ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration exception when reverting migration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-migrations

I have created the following Active Record Migration that adds and removes some indexes.

```
class FixIndexes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :table1, :field1, :unique => true

    remove_index :table2, :name => "index_table2_on_field1"
    remove_index :table2, :name => "index_table2_on_field2"

    remove_index :table3, :name => "index_table3_on_field1"
    add_index :table3, [:field1, :field2]
  end
end
```

When I run the migration (`$ bundle exec rake db:migrate`) it works fine as expected.

Unfortunately when I try to revert the migration (`$ bundle exec rake db:rollback`) it does not work and raises an `ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration` exception

```
==  FixIndexes: reverting =====================================================
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/migration/command_recorder.rb:42:in `block in inverse'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/migration/command_recorder.rb:40:in `map'
```

My questions are:

1. Why this is an irreversible migration? It just adding and
   removing some indexes, not data.
2. It will fix the problem if I use `def self.up` and `def self.down`
   instead of `def change`?
3. How can I revert now this changes without adding and removing the
   indexes manually from MySQL?

Comment: Using self.up and self.down would work!

Comment: @Pavan: That worked, thanks! Of course I had to define the inverse operations in the self.down. My understanding is if it Rails can do it in the self.down it should be able to do it in the .change, but ...

Answer (score 5):

**Only few commands are reversible(without manual commands) in Rails**. And they are

- add_column
- add_index
- add_timestamps
- create_table
- create_join_table
- remove_timestamps
- rename_column
- rename_index
- rename_table

*Refer [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Migration/CommandRecorder)*

Your migration contains `remove_index` which is not supported by `CommandRecorder` for Rollback.

If you check this [Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html)

> Some transformations are destructive in a manner that cannot be
>   reversed. Migrations of that kind should raise an
>   **ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration** exception in their down method.

Which is the case in yours and obviously results in `ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration` exception.

**Long Story short:** remove_index cannot be reversed without manual commands.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but actually it did reversed using the self.down method.

Comment: @Rafa Indeed you have specified that in your 2nd question! This is the answer for your 1st and 3rd question. Assuming you were aware about the `self.down`